# Center multiple div number counter

Tags: jquery, html, css, division

I already looked loads and tried several different codes and nothing has worked for me..

I have this website and I want to center this number counters in the middle.

I tried, text-align, margin 0 auto and nothing works or i have been typing it in the wrong place.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

this is the HTML:

```
<section class="bg-primary" id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">We've got what you need!</h2>
                    <hr class="light">
                    <p class="text-faded">We are a creative staffing agency that gets your brand in front of your core audience, for a one-to-one interaction. Creating an impactful and eganging brand experience.</p>
                    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">300</span></div>
                    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">78</span></div>
                    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">32</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the CSS:

```
#shiva

{

    margin: 25px;
    float: left;
}



.count
        {

  line-height: 100px;
  color:black;
  font-size:50px;
}
```

Comment: There is so many ways, this is just one of them: https://jsfiddle.net/4dekcan3/  FYI, IDs must be unique on document contex

Comment: If you dont want to change existing structure & fix this count alignment issue you can use following css property 
#shiva{
    margin: 25px;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    width:29%;    
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following

```
<div class="c">
    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">300</span></div>
    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">78</span></div>
    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">32</span></div>
</div>

.c {
    width: 350px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/zmtLatn9/

Comment: Excellent! I had to use a 400px width but that did the job! thanks

Comment: @TomasAlonsoRehor, to get a true centering without the need for a hardcoded width, I would put `text-align:center` on `.c` div (removing other styles) and make `shiva` divs `display:inline-block` (also changing shiva to a class)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">300</span></div>
    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">78</span></div>
    <div id="shiva"><span class="count">32</span></div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this......

```
<div class="parent">
     <div id="shiva"><span class="count">300</span></div>
     <div id="shiva"><span class="count">78</span></div>
     <div id="shiva"><span class="count">32</span></div>
</div>

.parent {
    margin:auto;
    display:table;
}
```